# Grunt, cloud deployment and compiled files

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, copy, cloud

I've recently started exploring grunt and I've done so by trying out the 
https://github.com/ng-vu/ng-express-boilerplate seed.

It uses a gruntfile to copy static assets, css, javascript to a destination folder with this code:

```
dist_js: {
    files: [{
        src: ['<%= app_files.js %>', '<%= vendor_files.js %>'],
        dest: '<%= dist_dir %>/public',
        cwd: '.',
        expand: true
     }]
}
```

where dist_dir is 'dist'.

Now in the config files it is specified that in development we want to serve assets, src and vendor files from their original location, so the configuration of express for development is as follows:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets')));
app.use('/src', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src')));
app.use('/vendor', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../vendor')));
```

In production, the code is:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

When I move this to production (specifically to openshift), the index.html template is served with all the script and link tags, but the scripts and css are not found. What I get is 'Cannot GET file.css' for example.

I run grunt build and compile on the cloud and the output is 'Done, without errors', but the files are nowhere to be found. I've tried one too many things and I've run out of ideas. Have I missed out something fundamental about grunt?

EDIT:
The problem was that the javascript files doing the routing are located inside src/server, so __dirname pointed to that location. Grunt however did the copying inside the project root.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/public')));
```

This fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you post a little more about your directory structure?

Comment: I cloned the seed (https://github.com/ng-vu/ng-express-boilerplate) and haven't changed much yet, just added some openshift variables to start it up properly on the cloud (also added an action hook for grunt).

Comment: Anyway you can post a link to your git repo?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/xtrinch/tdnegova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose your assets with a route.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/public')));`

You need to modify your `package.json` file to call grunt after running npm install.  To do this add the following.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server/app.js",
    "postintall": "grunt build; grunt compile"
}
```

Additionally it might be good to define a new grunt task that combines these two tasks.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
grunt.registerTask("prep-for-cloud", [ "compile", "build" ]);
```

Then your `package.json` would look like the following.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server/app.js",
    "postintall": "grunt prep-for-cloud"
}
```

Also you should add `grunt-cli` to your `package.json` file as a dependency.

Comment: Is the .openshift\action_hooks\build script not okay? Because my push logs indicate that grunt build and grunt compile are both run?

Comment: It honestly best to put it in your `package.json` as its a node feature and will allow you to move your app better across clouds.

Comment: Alright, but that's just different ways of doing the same thing and it didn't help the 404 problem. I put it in the build script because you have to change home directories on openshift, that way I don't have to change package.json file everytime I run it in development

Comment: Can you check the dir's on openshift to see if they exist and contain your file contents?

Comment: All the necessary the files are in dist/public/.. and there's also a bin/public folder (not sure why dist and bin?)
I suppose something must be wrong with my routing

Comment: So thats the issue, you are exposing the assets in dist/public but you don't have a route for that.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried running your app locally, it never starts and doesn't respond to requests..

Comment: Did you run it with grunt watch?

Comment: Yeah the seed project has it set up like that so that the gruntfile does the copying into the dist/public, but only in production, that's why there's separate configurations for development and production.. Locally running grunt watch is enough to run it. I don't have enough experience with this to say if it's a good setup or not.. Anycase I found the problem, will update the question